# Sampling with row number in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

Let's say I have a much bigger dataset than the one below:

```
df = data.frame(x = c("ciao mondo", "hello world", "ciao world","hello mondo","bye mondo","ciao ciao mondo"))
```

I want to sample randomly and without replacement a few rows and so I do:

```
sample(df$x,size = 3, replace = F)
```

The issue with that is that I no longer have the original row index of the sampled rows. My dataset is quite big so using anything like `grepl()` to retrieve the original row indices is inefficient.

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the row number into a column, and then sample rows from that data frame.

```
df$row = 1:nrow(df)
df[sample(nrow(df), 3, replace = F),]
```

result after `set.seed(0)`

```
               x row
6 ciao ciao mondo   6
1      ciao mondo   1
4     hello mondo   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sampling on the column, do the `sample` on the sequence of rows, thus it will return the row index which can be later used for subsetting the rows

```
i1 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = 3, replace = FALSE)
```